# ExtJS 4 - how to disable checkbox in a specific row

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a grid of data in ExtJS 4 which contains a checkbox column. I need to disable the checkbox programmatically after the grid has loaded, following an external AJAX call. (Basically, after making the AJAX call, I need to stop users from changing the checkbox. This is not a store update). I do have a reference to the row itself.

I have seen several similar questions, but they all seem to deal with disabling a row or cell edit when the data is initially loaded.

Comment: Can you post some code ? Do you want to disable the column that contains the checkbox(es) or just some of the checkboxes within that column ?

Comment: Ideally I would just want to disable the one checkbox that corresponds to the row. I am not sure what code I can post that may be helpful?

Comment: look at renderer config for Column

Comment: was trying to put an example but docs are down right now ... :P

Comment: @code4jhon when will the renderer be called? Will it be called when any field in the store is changed, or only when the field being rendered changes?

Comment: when the field being rendered changes, each column could have a different renderer function and this will get executed before the value for that specific column renders e.g renderer : function(value, meta){return value * 10;}

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you wan't to stop users editing your grid inline. In order to do this use the processEvent function on your grid and return false so any edit they try to make is immediately returned.

```
{
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    dataIndex: 'someModelReference',
    // Prevents toggling the checkbox inline
    processEvent: function() {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this does effectively stop the edit, it won't give the user a visual indication that the field can't be edited, which would be desirable.